# A Modular Diophantine Equation

Tags: modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

$a = (N \bmod c)\bmod d$

$b = (N \bmod d)\bmod c$

That is $a$ and $c$ is remainder of $N$ when divided by $c$ and $d$ in different order.

What can we say about $N$ if $a,b,c,d$ are known and $N < cd$?

Comment: Your use of mod in that way is, I believe, an abuse of notation. Do you perhaps mean that $a$ is set equivalent to the remainder obtained when you divide $N$ by $c$, under mod $d$?

Comment: This is a question that only to read can cause you a headache, and it is also not a pretty one. If you'd give some background and/or reasons to ask this question, plus some self work and effort you've put to answer it, then it'll look nicer...

Comment: removed the $\equiv$ sign. I am looking at successive remainders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without loss of generality, assume that $c<d$. Moreover assume that $x \bmod n$  denotes the unique representative in $[0,n-1]$.

The first remark is that $a=N \bmod c$, because (since $c<d$) this value is already reduced modulo $d$. For the other reduction, we only know that $N \bmod d=b+tc$, where $$0\leq t \leq \frac{(d-1)-b}{c}.$$

Now, from $N \bmod c$ and $N \bmod d$ you can easily reconstruct $N$ using the CRT (since $0\leq N <cd$).

In addition, if $N_t$ denotes the solution obtained for some acceptable value of $t$, we have $N_t=N_0+tc$.

---

Here is an example, take $c=11$, $d=101$, $a=2$ and $b=3$. Since $(d-4)/c\approx 8.8$, we have $t\in [0;8]$. This yields the following set of solutions:
$$
S=\{508,519,530,541,552,563,574,585,596\}
$$

Comment: When is the result unique? Is it if $\frac{d}{c} \in (-1.5,1.5)$?

Comment: @JAS I think it is clear everywhere that $c>0$ and $d>0$. But even with $d/c$ very close to one you can have multiple solutions. Take $c=11$, $d=13$, $a=4$ and $b=1$, you have two solutions: $92$ and $103$. The only criteria is the upper bound is gave on $t$, if it is less than $1$, you have unicity of the solution.

Comment: So $0<\frac{d-1-b}{c}<1\implies\mbox{unique solution}$? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, unless I am mistaken [need more characters than just yes :)]